# File descriptor error when subprocess call is used with event loop enabled in main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have been using asyncio to run subprocess calls in a separate thread. For this purpose I start an event loop in my main thread as per the recommendation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocess-and-threads .

Now when I use a normal subprocess call in the main thread, I start getting following file descriptor error after few iterations:

```
Exception ignored when trying to write to the signal wakeup fd:
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I have reproduced the problem in a small script and am seeing that the error goes away if I do not start the even loop in the main thread.

```
import asyncio
import subprocess
import time


def try_error():
    for i in range(1,500):
        print(i)
        try:
            subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(f"Exception raised {e.stderr}\nOutput {e.stdout}")



def definite_error():
    w = asyncio.get_child_watcher()
    l = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try_error()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    definite_error()
```

I am not sure why this error occurs and how to make it go away. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is the smallest subset of the code which can reproduce the error. In the original code, I run a `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` in a parallel thread. The normal subprocess call is part of third party code which call from the main thread and hence cannot modify it.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you didn't actually **start** the event loop. If you did, it would be draining the signal wakeup fd and the problem wouldn't occur.

Comment: I tried `l.run_until_complete(try_error())` after making `try_error` a co-routine. It still throws the same error.

Comment: Since `try_error` doesn't contain an `await`, making it a coroutine makes it a coroutine in name only. Try making it a coroutine and also adding `await asyncio.sleep(0)` - that should ensure that the event loop is actually _running_ during your process creation.

Comment: In the long run, mixing the sync `subprocess` module and asyncio will attract problems. Have you considered switching to `asyncio.subprocess`?

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342 Adding the `await asyncio.sleep(0)` helps. I had modified the library file to use asynio.subprocess which also helps. Guess using a sleep is much smaller change. This might be an issue if we cannot modify the third party code which uses subprocess calls. Any way can you post you comment as answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code doesn't actually **start** the event loop, it just obtains the event loop instance.

Note that the event loop needs to be **running**, so it's not enough to turn `def try_error()` into `async def` and run it with `run_until_complete()` to fix the problem. You must also add an `await` to give the event loop a chance to run accumulated tasks, such as draining the signal wakeup fd.

For example, `await asyncio.sleep(0)` is such a minimal await, which will temporarily [yield control](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284) to the event loop and allow your code to proceed.